# Adjust title vertically to inside the plot - vjust not working

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to place the title inside the plot instead at the default top position.
Here is a simple code snippet

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = rnorm(10, 1, 2))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
   geom_line() +
   ggtitle("Demo") + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = -3))
```

In the past I was able to do this by varying `vjust` value, but now it is not working. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I assume you use `ggplot2_2.0.0`? Because quite a few changes have been made in this version, you might wish to add this info to your post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In [the ggplot issue "vjust not working in v 2.0 for plot.title?"](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1435), Hadley writes:

"All text elements now have a margin, which by default scale with the font 
size in the theme. This leads to nicer spacing, particularly at large font
sizes. This means hacks with `vjust` and `hjust` no longer work. Instead,
use the `margin()` parameter of `element_text()`"

Play around with the `t` and `b` arguments in `margin` to adjust the title, e.g.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Demo") + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, b = -20)))
```

[image]

See `?margin` for further arguments.

---

Note that you should use the `margin` argument for `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y` as well:

```
ggplot() + ggtitle("this is title") + xlab("this is x") + ylab("this is y") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = -10)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -10)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = -10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know what T,R,B,L represent? I did not see an explanation on the link.

Comment: `t`op, `r`ight, `b`ottom, `l`eft, I assume.