# ggplot how to place Title in x and y coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to place ggplot title inside the plot on particular x and Y cordinates. Please note that I am not asking about annotate text but ggtitle. I need use gganmate and change the title per frame.

[image]

I have tried but the tilt stuck at left top corner

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b=-25), size = 30)) +
  labs(title = "title")
```

Comment: please include your data and what you have tried

Comment: so you want `geom_text`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust title vertically to inside the plot - vjust not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805506/adjust-title-vertically-to-inside-the-plot-vjust-not-working)

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen  i used theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b=-25), size = 30)) +
  labs(title = "title") but its not helping

Comment: in what way is it not working? Did you get an error? The more helpful you are ,and the more effort you put into this the quicker we are able to help your. Please make sure to include any code in your actual question